# SQL Server drops previous error in Try-Catch block (Also in 2019)

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

I have a problem with error handling. I'm using Try/Catch-blocks and this works very good for me. But in some cases there's not only one error raised but more. Then I'm only getting the last error message.

Let me give an example :

When executing this block :

```
alter table [dbo].[table] 
   add constraint [somefk]    
       foreign key ([somecol]) references [dbo].[parenttab] ([someid])
```

it raises 2 errors:

> Msg 1778, Level 16, State 0, Line 7
> Column 'dbo.parenttab.someid' is not the same data type as referencing column 'table.somecol' in foreign key 'somefk'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

So far, so good. But in case I put the statement in a Try/Catch block, the first message (1778) "is eaten" by someone.

In the end, I'm getting only the second message with the non-significant text :(

So, what I'm missing is a kind of an error collection, well-known from programming languages or frameworks. Or is it just a "Missing feature" in SQL Server...? How can I get the proceeding error message?

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards!

fksof

Comment: Different types of handling errors will have different results. For example, using THROW `BEGIN CATCH; THROW; END CATCH;` will show both errors. What are you doing with the errors?

Comment: As a generalisation: SQL Server error handling can be "flaky" in certain scenarios, this is one of them. This article may help you: https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/02/04/capture-multiple-errors-in-try-catch-by-using-throw-statement/

Comment: The error should be shown if they occur. I'm using some stored procedures for deployment purposes. Having only the scond error is not sufficient. I will try the "THROW"-variant and get back later with the results.

Comment: Just be aware that a throw exits the stored procedure/code block there (e.g., similar to just not having a try-catch block). I usually use it as part of error checking in transactions e.g., `BEGIN TRY BEGIN TRANSACTION; <code> COMMIT TRANSACTION; END TRY BEGIN CATCH; IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; THROW; END CATCH;` However, the main point was to ask what your catch block looked like - if you have the code there, people can suggest changes/updates.

Comment: As you already mentioned THROW exits the block. So this drives me not further... Nevertheless thx a lot :)

Comment: Also thx for the link to "...sqlwithmanoj...". This reflects exactly my problem. I want to control how the response occurs. Using THROW prevents that while ERROR_MESSAGE() only delivers the last error :/